# Assign match_parent as a dimen programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-resources

I'm using `dimens.xml` file to assign values for different layout sizes(i.e **dimens.xml@values**, **dimens.xml@values-sw600dp**).

When trying to set a dimen as `wrap_Content` or `match_parent` I'm using the following way:

```
<resources>
    <item name="match_parent" format="integer" type="dimen">-1</item>
    <dimen name="popup_width">@dimen/match_parent</dimen>
</resources>
```

and it works perfectly when using this dimen inside the layout xml file, but when trying to use it programmatically like when declaring a popup window:

```
PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.popup_width),
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true);
pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 40, 0);
```

it doesn't work at all and it considers like if I passed a `-1dp` values to it(it performs direct referencing), so the layout is ruined at all.

So how can I declare the match_parent dimen in the `dimens.xml` file in order to use it efficiently in my code? or how even can I use the current dimen form efficiently in my code?

Comment: `match_parent` and `wrap_content` are not dimensions.

Comment: @CommonsWare so, there isn't a way to use any of them programmatically as a dynamic dimension ?!! or even as anything else ?!!

Comment: My first question is, why do you need to use `match_parent` as a dimension programmatically? You could find the width of the device and set this width as the width of your `PopupWindow` programmatically.

Comment: it can't be like that, as I want to set the width to be match_parent at some devices and let's say 700dp at others, so it has to be a dynamic parameter which assigned for each different layout in its corresponding `dimens.xml` file

Comment: Create a boolean resource (e.g., `use_match_parent`), set to `true` and `false` in appropriate resource sets. If `use_match_parent` is true, pass `MATCH_PARENT` to your `PopupWindow`. Otherwise, pass your dimension.

Comment: @CommonsWare nice, that will be a pretty good work-around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using `-1.0px` for representing `match_parent`, and `-2.0px` for representing `wrap_content` as `dp` is scaling with different screens density unlike `px` which is not reacting to different screen densities(and that what I need in my solution):

```
<dimen name="popup_width">-1.0px</dimen>  <!-- for match_parent -->

<dimen name="popup_height">-2.0px</dimen>  <!-- for wrap_content -->
```

and then I used it programmatically like:

```
PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, (int)mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.popup_width),
        (int)mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.popup_height), true); // notice that they have to be casted as int
```